# Having problem with simple C++ file handling program

Tags: c++, file, oop, overloading, file-handling

My code is not working as expected. When I run the program and try to output n ( on line ABC ) , the program displays only "New" on the screen. why isn't the program reading the rest of the file? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class stateData{
private:
    string name, capital;
    int area, admissionYear, admissonOrder;
public:
friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& input, stateData &state);
friend ostream& operator<<(ofstream& output, stateData &state);

};


ifstream& operator >>(ifstream &input, stateData &state){
    string name, capital,n;
    int area, admissionYear, admissionOrder;
    input >> n;
    input>>capital;
    input>>area;
    input>>admissionYear;
    input>>admissionOrder;
    state.name=n;
    cout << n;  // LINE ABC
}


int main(){
    stateData states[50];
    string n;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    int hashTable[101];
    infile.open("Ch9_Ex8_data.txt");
    if (infile.fail()){
        cout << "Sorry, file could not be opened. ";
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++){
        infile>> states[i];
    }
}
}
```

Given below is the contents of the file: "

```
New Hampshire 
Concord
9304 1788 9
Massachusetts
Boston
8257 1788 6
```

...

Comment: @cigien thanks for spotting the mistake. changed it, but to no effect. still only displays "new"

Comment: [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)

Comment: @user202729 im still reading the file line by line, even though it may not be till the end of the file. input>> n first reads a line and the next time the statement is executed, even the next line read automatically?

Comment: No it doesn't. Read the linked question carefully.

Comment: FYI: [operator>>(std::string)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) One of the reasons to stop input is the occurrence of a whitespace: _`std::isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next character c in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream)._ Hence `input >> n;` reads `New` but leaves ` Hampshire` in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to the way the input is being read from the file and how spaces and newlines is handled by the ">>" operator in C++. When you use input >> n; in your operator function, it reads input until it encounters whitespace, which means it stops reading at the first space or newline character.

In your file, the state name "New Hampshire" contains a space. So, when you write input >> n;, it only reads "New" and stops at the space before "Hampshire". The rest of the lines don't get read as expected.

To read the full line for the state name, you should use getline instead of the ">>" operator.